# R: Does fixest package support panel data analysis?

Tags: r, panel, fixed, fixest

I am working with fixest package. Great results so far.

My data could be set as a panel. Is there any way for fixest to run run panel data analysis.

My model looks something like this:

```
model <- fenegbin(incident~ treatdummy + 
poverty + 
industry + 
rural  + 
offset(log(pop))|state,
               se= "HC1",
            data=subset(df1))
```

Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use the `panel.id` argument in your estimation function to get access to a bunch of panel methods.

From the [documentation](https://lrberge.github.io/fixest/reference/femlm.html):

> panel.id
> The panel identifiers. Can either be: i) a one sided formula (e.g. panel.id = ~id+time), ii) a character vector of length 2 (e.g. panel.id=c('id', 'time'), or iii) a character scalar of two variables separated by a comma (e.g. panel.id='id,time'). Note that you can combine variables with ^ only inside formulas (see the dedicated section in feols).

See [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fixest/vignettes/fixest_walkthrough.html#lagging-variables) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Yes `Fixest` was designed to run fixed effect estimations. You can follow the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bQZGDKrbHoA) here to have a quick idea about how to use `Fixest` to your panel analysis.